# Função para verificar se um número é divisível por outro

Tags: javascript

O objetivo desse exercicio é retornar se o número de entrada é divisível por `x` ou não.

Seu programa receberá sempre de entrada: um número inteiro e outro número inteiro representando `x` e deverá imprimir na tela se o primeiro número de entrada é divisível por `x`.

A entrada será sempre dois números inteiros.

A saída deverá ser sempre true ou false.

Sample Input 0

```
10 2
```

Sample Output 0

```
true
```

Explanation 0

10 é divísivel por 2 por que ao dividir 10 por 2 o resto é 0.

Esse é o código que estou usando:

```
function solucao(numero, x) {
// seu código aqui
    return numero % x == 0; {
        console.log(solucao (10,2))
        if (resto == 0) {
          console.log("true");
        } else {
            console.log("false");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: e qual a dificuldade? posta ai na pergunta o código que já fez até agora e onde tem dificuldade

Comment: Então, estou perdido na questão, como eu faria a entrada em código e tal

Comment: se não sabe nem por onde começar melhor voltar a estudar o básico. Aqui no SO não damos essa ajuda, podemos te ajudar com um problema específico mas não vamos fazer o código pra você, até porque assim não vai aprender :)
pesquise no site que provavelmente vai achar pergunta sobre todo o básico de javascript, como ler uma informação, validar, etc

Comment: o codigo que eu estava tentando era esse

Comment: function solucao(numero, x) {

    const resto = numero % 2;

  if (resto == 0) {
    console.log("true")
  } 
}

solucao(10);

Comment: mas ta errado, e to meio perdido! Tentando aprender só, mas ta osso

Comment: agora ta melhor Leônidas, [clique aqui para editar sua pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/495922/edit) e adicione esse código lá

Comment: Editei, poderia me dar alguma dica?

Comment: Vc está vendo se o número é divisível por 2, e não por `x`, então deveria ser `function solucao(numero, x) { return numero % x == 0; }` e para chamar, `console.log(solucao(10, 2))` (para ver se 10 é divísivel por 2), `console.log(solucao(90, 3))` (para ver se 90 é divisível por 3), etc - ah sim, também fiz a função retornar `true` ou `false`, em vez de imprimir o valor (e vc só imprime se for true, mas e se não for?) - pois assim quem chamou a função só pega o resultado (true ou false) e decide o que fazer com ele (podendo até imprimir uma mensagem, se for o caso)

Comment: A Stackoverflow aumenta a entreajuda dos desenvolvedores de software. A tua pergunta não me parece útil para ti, nem para a maior parte da comunidade da Stackoverflow. Mesmo que te desse a resposta, não irias perceber o porquê da minha resposta.
Tens a função mal implementada e mal chamada...
Eu sugiro-te a fazer um curso básico na Khan academy, por exemplo, ou até mesmo ver uns tutoriais no YouTube. Não desistas, o que interessa é querer aprender!

Answer (score 1):

O operador de igualdade [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) verifica se seus dois operandos são iguais, retornando um resultado [booleano](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean), `true` ou `false`. Assim não precisando testar o [resto](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#m%C3%B3dulo) para imprimir strings com o resultados.

Quando uma declaração [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) é usada em um corpo de função, a execução dessa função é parada e o código posterior a declaração não será interpretado. Se especificado, um dado valor é retornado à quem chamou a função. Se a expressão for omitida, [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) será retornado.

```js
//n= é o numero atestar a divisibilidade.
//d= é o divisor.
function solucao(n, d) {
  return n % d == 0;
}

console.log(solucao(10, 2))

console.log(solucao(7, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou postar aqui alguns comentários sobre o teu código:

```js
// aqui não está usando "x" e também não está passando esse valor , então pode remover
function solucao(numero) {   // <- sem o "x"
    const resto = numero % 2; 
    if (resto == 0) { 
       console.log("true") 
    } else {
       console.log("false")  // <- faltou isso, que é o "else" caso o resto não seja zero
    }
};


solucao(10);
solucao(7);
```

Comment: Não sei o pq mas diz que errado! Na questão diz mais embaixo que "A entrada será sempre dois números inteiros" e "A saída deverá ser sempre true ou false."

Comment: Eu usando esse codigo:

function solucao(numero, x) {
 // seu código aqui
        return numero % x == 0; {
            console.log(solucao (10,2))
            if (resto == 0) {
              console.log("true");
            }
        } 
    
    
}
ficaria faltando só dar a saída de true ou false

Comment: está errado baseado na sua pergunta, está esperando a variável "x" que não é usada. Se precisar corrigir edite a pergunta, mas acho que isso já deve ajudar a resolver :)

Comment: Fiz a edição coloquei a questão toda e como estou utilizando o codigo agora

Comment: isso está resolvido então? se tiver outra dúvida diferente pode abrir outra pergunta